# SAS to ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, sas

```
`rsubmit;
 Proc sql ;
 &c_oradb;
Create table output.want as
SELECT * from connection to oracle
(Select *
From data.ref_codes
Where lowcase(Description) like '%vac%');
DISCONNECT from oracle;
Quit;
```

`

Error:

> ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00904: "LOWCASE": invalid identifier. SQL statement:

I am trying to run this code but getting the above error. I understand that variable names are case sensitive while connecting to oracle but why isn't `lowcase` function identified?

Comment: If that's about Oracle, then change `lowcase` to `lower` and it should be OK.

Comment: Thank you! it works :) Can you tell me what other things might work in sas but not oracle? Is there some paper to refer?

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with the the Oracle documentation. It is free, online and pretty comprehensive. Of course, you are going to have to use your skill and judgement to figure out things like `lower()` is the Oracle equivalent of `lowcase()`. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions094.htm#i1043828).

Comment: @SAW - I don't think there's such a paper, I just wrote what I know that works in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the `SCHEMA` "data" exists and it has the table/view/materialized view `ref_codes` in it, which has a column called "Description", then the statement should be:

```
(Select *
From data.ref_codes
Where lower(Description) like '%vac%');
```

Cheers